# Hazelcast v3.5 is Loading 1 key at a time

Tags: hazelcast

I have migrated my application from Hazelcast v2.5 to v3.5 recently.  With Hazelcast v2.5, my application startup time is around 20 seconds after upgrading to latest version, the time is increased to 240 seconds. That is because Hazelcast v3.5 is loading 1 or 2 keys at a time. I read the documentation, it says that 'Because of 277 partitions'.

I would like to increase my application start-up time by setting 1000 keys at a time. Is there any setting to control that in Hazelcast v3.5

Thanks, 
Venu

Comment: How many keys does you application have?

Comment: I am having 15 map stores. Each having different keys. The keys ranging from 10-10000.

Comment: Each partition loads in chunks of up to 1000. Configurable with hazelcast.map.load.chunk.size setting. For the number of keys you have it will not reach 1000 because of 271 partitions.

Comment: But how Hazelcast v2.5 is able to load 1000 keys at a time?

Comment: 2.5 is loading per node as opposed to per partition and this behaviour changed with v3.0. For the larger maps you should still see it loading about 30 keys at once (10k/271). Is that not the case? Would be great if you could create a reproducer test case so that its easier to verify.

Comment: Btw, it's possible to decrease the number of partitions

Answer (score 3):

Hazelcast 3.5 loads data in chunks of 1000 by default and that's configurable with `hazelcast.map.load.chunk.size` property. However, each partition loads its own set of keys and there are 271 partitions by default.

Since the number of keys you have is not large you could try decreasing the number of partitions to a lower prime number. The property is: `hazelcast.partition.count`